# Jenkins Build Errors

Tags: ros, jenkins, bloom-release, debian, release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I recently released a new version of a meta-package using the updated bloom 0.5.13 version. Since the update the souredeb Jenkins job has been repeatedly failing.

Here are the errors being displayed in the Jenkins console output:
﻿

```
dpkg-source: error: syntax error in ros-indigo-multisense-3.3.7/debian/control at line 10: block lacks the 'Package' field
dpkg-buildpackage: error: dpkg-source -i -I --before-build ros-indigo-multisense-3.3.7 gave error exit status 25
debuild: fatal error at line 1350:
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -d -us -uc -i -I -S failed
gbp:error: debuild -i -I returned 29
gbp:error: Couldn't run 'debuild -i -I -S -uc -us --lintian-opts --suppress-tags newer-standards-version'
Usage: include_folder.py [options]
```

The full console output can be found here:
http://jenkins.ros.org/job/ros-indigo-multisense_sourcedeb/93/console

Here is the relese repository:
https://github.com/carnegieroboticsllc/multisense_ros-release

Can anyone confirm these error are not caused by a incorrect package configuration? Also is there any documentation on the build process Jenkins is using to create the package debians?

Thanks,
Matt Alvarado

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198398/jenkins-build-errors/) by [malvaradoCRL](https://answers.ros.org/users/20950/malvaradocrl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2014-11-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That sounds like the bloom bug https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/bloom/pull/329

You need to update to the latest release of bloom 0.5.14 and rerelease your package.
(If it is not yet available in the public repos give it some hours.)

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1